# Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratic-forms

So on the topic of sum of two squares, I wanted to see how to extend that to what primes can be expressed as $x^2+ny^2$. I think the way to do this is to show that we can contract a binary quadratic form assuming we can find a number such that $27$ or $64$, in this case, is a quadratic residue $\mod p$, but I'm not sure how to continue.

Is there specific set of primes that can be expressed in terms of modular relations or residual relations? How would you solve this is the case of $27, 64$, or the general case of $n$?

Comment: This is in general an interesting question. For example you can prove that $p=x^{2}+17y^{2}$ has a solution if and only if $\alpha^{2}(\alpha^{2}-1)\equiv 4\mod{p}$ has a solution *and* that -17 is a quadratic residue mod p (the smallest such prime is 53). For more on this interesting story you can check out the book "Primes of the form $x^{2}+ny^{2}$ by Cox (where he treats the case when $n>0$). To actually prove what I wrote above takes a bit of class field theory to do, so it's not really elementary number theory.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Primes-Form-x2-ny2-Multiplication/dp/1118390180

Comment: Hi, I'm quite familiar with class groups and genera, so what's the proof of the statements you mentioned above @YumekuiMath

Comment: @SultanofQuizikhstan Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-17})$ and let $L$ be the class field of $K$ (you can prove that $[L:K]=4$, i.e. the ideal class group of $\mathcal{O}_{K}$ is of order 4). Then you can prove that we can choose $\alpha=\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{17}}{2}}$ so $L=K(\alpha)$. Then the main theorem of §5 of Cox' book tells us that for odd primes p we have $p=x^{2}+17y^{2}$ if and only if p does not divide 17, -17 is a quadratic residue mod p and there is a solution of $f(z)\equiv 0\mod{p}$ where $f(z)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ (which you can show is $z^{2}(z^{2}-1)-4$).

Answer (score 5):

A whole book can be written on the topic. In fact, David Cox, no relation to me, has written such a book. Maybe this will get closed for being an overly broad question.

If you have a specific $n$ in mind, you could try finding a few of the corresponding primes expressible by $x^2 + ny^2$ and then looking them up in the OEIS.

Let's try for example $n = 2$. We find that $3, 11, 17, 19$ are of the form $x^2 + 2y^2$. An OEIS search gives more than twenty results, so maybe we should add two more numbers to see if we can narrow it down to a single result. $3, 11, 17, 19, 41, 43$ still gives mroe results than I'd like, but it's easier to find ["Primes congruent to $\{1, 3\} \bmod 8$; or, odd primes of form $x^2 + 2y^2$."](http://oeis.org/A033200)

Or how about $n = -2$? These turn out to be the primes $p$ such that $$\left( \frac{2}{p} \right) = 1$$ (that's the Legendre symbol).

Do note that $2$ comes up in a lot of these results. Clearly if $x = 0$ and $y = 1$ or $i$, we'll have $x^2 + ny^2 = 2$ for $n = 2$ or $-2$.

Comment: So for example n=64 or 27, what is the process for finding these modular congruences? I have a hunch that for 27 , p is 1 mod 3 and 2 is a residue, and for 64 p is 1 mod 4, but I'm not sure how to proceed in proving it