# Infinitude of primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$

Tags: number-theory

The problem is: "Can we know about the infinitude of prime numbers of the form $x^2+ny^2$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$?"
The proof in the case $n=1$ is given by Euler, he proved that a prime number is of the form $x^2+y^2$ if and only if it congruent $1$ modulo $4$. Hence, there are infinity many of them.
I have already known the proof in case $n=2$ and $n=3$. 
For negative $n$, its seem impossible to prove when $n=-k^2$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2977857/primes-of-the-form-x2ny2). It is explained in Cox's book.

Comment: Actually _every_ prime except $2$ has the form $x^2-y^2$, and those of the form $4m+1$ are also $x^2-4y^2$.

Comment: For $n=-k^2$, we can only have primes when $x=ky+1$. Then $x^2+ny^2=2ky+1$ is prime infinitely often by Dirichlet's theorem.