# The diophantine equation $ a^2 + p b^2 = c^2 + p d^2 = q $ and related ring theory questions.

Tags: ring-theory, diophantine-equations, factoring, quadratic-forms, unique-factorization-domains

Inspired by norms of integral domains I started to think about the related diophantine equation for the norms.

Let $2 < p,q $ be given primes.

Consider the diophantine equation for positive integers

$$ a^2 + p b^2 = c^2 + p d^2 = q $$

Where $0 < a,b,c,d$ and $0 < (a-c)^2 + (b - d)^2$.

In other words we want 2 distinct representations of the prime $q$ by norms of the form $x^2 + p y^2$. This is basicly studying the norm for $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-p}]$.

How to handle this ?

Quadratic residues probably relate to this.

Also I am unsure how this relates to $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-p}]$ being a UFD or not , or to the the class number of it.

And I am also insecure about how it relates to Euclidean norms or multiplicative norms.

I know for instance the Gaussian integers or Eisenstein integers have multiplicative norms :

if $j,k$ are elements then $A = j k $ implies $N(A) = N(j)N(k)$.

and I know they only have one representation of a prime $q$.
In fact that is used in the proof of their UFD and in justifying factoring methods for them.

It seems these 2 properties combined, implies being a UFD ?

I say combined here because I know for instance that the norm $a^2 + 17 b^2$ for the ring $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-17}]$ is multiplicative yet the ring $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-17}]$ is not a UFD !!

Not sure how this relates to these diophantines.

Maybe it does not relate to these diophantines or norms at all and it is just my imagination ?

Is the number of representations (here $2$) equal to the class number if the norm is multiplicative ?

I read some stuff about ring theory but I did not learn or at least did not understand how to do these things and look at them properly.

My apologies for asking maybe more than 1 thing but I suspect they are all related and understanding one implies understanding the other.

The extra questions are more a kind of context.

The main question is the diophantine and an answer to that could get the accept.

I am aware of the  Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity , but that does not answer my question(s).

For those who want to give a very general answer, I am mainly into rings that have a finite amount of units.

---

***edit***

I am aware that apparantly Euler and others came up with a method to solve the related equation but for COMPOSITE $q$.

Maybe that can help.

say $q = A q_2$

$$ a^2 + p b^2 = c^2 + p d^2 = A q_2 $$

If $0 < gcd(a,b,c,d,q_2)$ we might be in business.

Then again Euler did not even attempt the case for none-composite and the idea might miss solutions.
So I am not very optimistic yet.

---

***edit 2***

A few insightful links :

Norms are always multiplicative :

[When is the norm of a ring $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-p}]$ multiplicative?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4724828/when-is-the-norm-of-a-ring-bbb-z-sqrt-p-multiplicative)

and the general equation here

[A generalization of Euler Factorization with $N = m a^2 + n b^2 = m c^2 + n d^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4712807/a-generalization-of-euler-factorization-with-n-m-a2-n-b2-m-c2-n-d2)

( it has a bounty at the moment !)

---

Comment: -1 Please gather your thoughts into a coherent question before posting them here. As it stands this is just some rambling sprinkled with buzzwords.

Comment: This looks very similar to this question here :  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4712807/a-generalization-of-euler-factorization-with-n-m-a2-n-b2-m-c2-n-d2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See:
[Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2977857/primes-of-the-form-x2ny2)

Suppose $\mathbb{Z}[i \sqrt{p}]$ is a UFD then there is unique factorization of $q$ into prime elements in the ring.

Lets say we have unique factorization of $q$ as : $q = \prod_i z_{i}$
where $z_i$ are prime elements in the ring and various solutions come from various ways of grouping this product.

Since we have $q = (a+i\sqrt{p}b) \times (a-i\sqrt{p}b)$,
2 non-trivial factorizations exist iff $a+i\sqrt{p}b$ is not a prime element and can be further factorized assuming $\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{p}]$ is a UFD. This is because if $a+i\sqrt{p}b$ is a prime element there is only one unique way of combining the factorization of $q$ into solutions.

Hence,
$a+i\sqrt{p}b = (c+i\sqrt{p}d) \times (c'+i\sqrt{p}d')$

But then $Norm(a+i\sqrt{p}b) = Norm(c+i\sqrt{p}d) \times Norm(c'+i\sqrt{p}d')$ which cannot be prime unless $Norm(c+i\sqrt{p}d) = 1$

But $Norm(c+i\sqrt{p}d) = 1$ has only $c = 1,-1$ as solution.

Hence there exists a unique solution if $\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{p}]$ is a UFD.

Check if this ring is a UFD.

Further Analysis in case the ring is not a UFD:
$$a^2+pb^2 = c^2 + p d^2 = q$$

Now, $$a^2 + pb^2 = c^2 + p d^2 \implies a^2 - c^2 = p (d^2 - b^2) \implies (a+c)(a-c) = p(d^2-b^2) \implies (a+c)(a-c) = p (d^2 - b^2) = p(d+b)(d-b) $$ $$\implies \ one \ possible \ two \ solutions \  a =(p(d+b) + d-b)/2, c = (p(d+b) - (d-b))/2  \ for \ any \ b,d$$

The only thing we need to conclude is that $a^2 + pb^2 = q$ is a prime number $\implies$ for any  $$q = \frac{(p(d+b) + d-b)^2}{4}+pb^2$$ a prime number, we have two different solutions.

So two solution exists if there exists a solution $d,b$ to the equation,
$$q = \frac{(p(d+b) + d-b)^2}{4}+pb^2 = Norm \left(\frac{(p(d+b) + d-b)}{2}+i\sqrt{p} b \right)$$ or for some $d,b$ this number turns out to be prime.

Hence for this possible factorization of $p(d+b)(d-b)$ into $(a+c)(a-c)$, we have that, if there exists a solution $a^2+pb^2 = q$ then another solution exists iff $$a = \frac{(p(d+b) + d-b)}{2}$$ is solvable for some value of $d$. In other words iff $2a+b-pb$ is divisible by $p+1$.

By various possible factorizations of $p(d^2-b^2)$ into $(a+c)(a-c)$ and solving for $a,c$, you can find out all possibilities for existence of two solutions.

Comment: why is $a$ even and $c$ odd ? WHY can they not both be even or both be odd ?

Comment: if both are even or both are odd then $a^2+pb^2$ will be even which cannot be equal to odd prime $q$.

Comment: no ! a and c ! not a and b !

Comment: $a$ is even $c$ is odd is just one of the cases i am considering. See that i have also mentioned the case that all solutions are of $a$ and $c$ even or both odd also.

Comment: Does a non-UFD imply two solutions for at least one $q$ ? ( I think so )
You set conditions on p when there are two solutions , but you do not explain when one has 2 solutions or what they are ?
I assume maybe knowing if there are 2 solutions is equivalent to being a non-UFD or not ?

Comment: knowing there are 2 solutions imply the ring is not UFD. I mentioned that "further analysis in case ring is not UFD". If the ring is UFD solution is unique.

Comment: Yes but does a non-UFD imply there are 2 solutions ?

Comment: Can you give a formula for$ a, b, c, d$ when given a $q$ ?

Comment: For example, for $q \leq p$ there is no solution at all whether UFD or not. UFD guarantees only uniqueness if solution exists and not the solution. For $q = p+4$ there cannot be 2 solutions since $a = 2$ uniquely and hence $b = 1$ for this case whether it is a UFD or not. So not being a UFD does not mean 2 solution exsits since it does not happen for $q = p+4$, if $p+4$ is a prime. for $q = p+4$, $a = 2$, $b = 1$ is a unique solution. For example $p = 223$, $ q = 227$ has unique solution but $p = 223$ is not a UFD.

Comment: I have given a formula for when 2 solution exists. This is only one of the situation where 2 solution exists. From the derivation you can deduce when all 2 solution exists. Cheers !. If you are happy with my answer, accept it by clicking to the left of my answer.

Comment: I will consider it ! thanks !

Comment: I did not downvote. Who did and why ?

Comment: I Dont know man

Comment: Ok , the part about UFD is correct. But the non-UFD part is not so good. Notice that having $a$ or $b$ is equivalent, we compute the one from the other. Similar with $c$ and $d$. Now that also implies having $a,c$ or $b,d$ is already have our 2 ways.
Then we see you writing a formula for $a$ and $c$ in terms of $b,d$. This does not help, we do not have $b,d$ if we did we were already done by the above argument. Then you go on asking to factor a function of $d,b$ into $(a+c)(a-c)$ what is even worse ; having $d,b$ is already the solution as is having $a,c$. Now you may argue ...

Comment: ...they are not explicitly given , but you also did not give a formula for those $b+d$ etc so that does not help. We do not know how to compute $ " b+d " $ without a formula for it , unless we have $b$ and $d$ already ... but that would mean already having solved the problem.  
Let me go on , maybe you think but what if one of the forms is known , you can compute the other ? 
Well for instance your formula for $a$ involves $b$ and $d$ but having $b$ implies knowing $a$ already , INDEPENDANT if we know $d$ or not. See the problem ?

Comment: if there exists a solution, $a,b$  then solve for $d$ using $a = \frac{p(d+b)+d-b}{2}$ (if possible) and you obtain $c =  \frac{p(d+b)-(d-b)}{2}$. So given $a,b$ i am solving for $c,d$, a new solution if $a = \frac{p(d+b)+d-b}{2}$  is solvable. You can derive  new conditions by other factorization of $p(d+b)(d-b)$ and equating the factors to $(a+c)$ and $a-c$. Although in a convoluted way finally have $c,d = f(a,b)$ iff certain $a = g(d,b)$ is solvable. The point is $g(d,b)$ is linear in factors of $p(d+b)(d-b)$. So it helps to solve a linear function although for each possible factorization.

Comment: thanks , I will look into it. I advice to clarify it in the answer ( to avoid downvoters and confusion )

Comment: How did you find that formula for $a$ resp $c$ anyway ??

Comment: From $(a+c)(a-c) = p(d+b)(d-b)$we consider by one possible factorization $a+c = p(d+b)$, $a-c = d-b$. Now solve for $a,c$ from these 2 equations. Consider different factorization and you get different solutions. I have edited the answer to finally tell the conclusion.

Comment: I finally accepted. Might add additional questions as new question. I could let you know here. But I will think and compute myself first.

Comment: Sure..but atleast this should help you work out some explicit cases.